# How is the rules of calculating a value named in C++

Tags: c++

Ok, this is a hard (for me) to explain what exactly I'm asking for, but I'll try it anyway...

I'm trying to explain to a person, who is learning C++, how an expression is calculated.
More specifically, why this:

```
5 / 2
```

gives `2` and why that:

```
5.0 / 2.0
```

gives an expected `2.5`.

My explanation says it is because `Integer value / Integer value = Integer value`. And this is the *clu* of my question: **how is that rule called?** I always thought it is "Type Algebra", but putting that on Google shows this term is rather Haskell related.

So, is the rule describing how operations and type of expressions in C++ depends on the types of values/variables somehow called? And an extra question: is it related only to C++ (I mean: this term is used only in C++ related material)?

Comment: It's called "type coercion", "numeric conversion" or [implicit type conversion](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/implicit-type-conversion-coercion/): http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: Read this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions

Comment: A "type algebra" is an algebra *of* types; it lets reason about types algebraically (without caring much about what concrete types are involved, similar to how "normal" algebra does not concern itself much with numbers). It's not specific to Haskell and is not really related to arithmetic. It's possible that the term you're looking for is "type system".

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for topics like:

- Promotion rules
- Implicit conversions
- Arithmetic conversions

Other stuff like operator precedence may also apply depending on the expression.